# Laravel Redis Driver Put Method Fails

Tags: php, caching, laravel, redis

I'm having trouble getting Redis to save keys in my Laravel app. If you look at the function below, what's happening is 'ERROR' is logging everytime. I'm using $this->cache because I've abstracted the cache into a repository and I won't get into how that's working because I'm pretty sure the issue is more around how I'm trying to save keys and use tags.

```
public function put($key, $value, $minutes = null)
{
    if (is_null($minutes)) {
        $minutes = $this->minutes;
    }

    if ($this->cache->tags($this->tag)->put($key, $value, $minutes)) {
        \Log::info('SUCCESS');
    } else {
        \Log::info('ERROR');
    }
}
```

I've been monitoring Redis activity as well and posted an example below. I'm a bit confused about what I see and what with it could possibly be wrong. Any clarity would be appreciated!

```
1420219689.948926 [0 127.0.0.1:35485] "SELECT" "0"
1420219689.949571 [0 127.0.0.1:35485] "GET" "homestead-app:tag:products:key"
1420219689.949979 [0 127.0.0.1:35485] "GET" "homestead-app:98b849a1a2ca908696ccc4595a070d57c737cf5c:f55cfb86c4764d10af6d3814d4760afd"
```